# Как при помощи iptables разделить соединения?

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables

Я написал приложения для обработки пакетов в пользовательском пространстве.
Схема сети такова:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Её суть такова что я меняю заголовки пакета вплоть до 4 уровня.
В данный момент имею следующие правила. Порт 4222 служебный.

```
#firewall A
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens18.100 -p tcp -m tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -i veth100 -p tcp -m tcp ! --sport 4222 ! --dport 4222 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 2
#firewall B
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens19.88 -p tcp -m tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -i veth88 -p tcp -m tcp ! --sport 22 ! --dport 22 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 2
```

Но хотелось бы узнать как разделить соединения и возможно  чтобы инициированное соединение из сети **172.16.100.0/24**  и ответы от **10.0.88.11/24** ушли на две очереди по примеру выше, а инициированное соединение из **10.0.88.1/24** так ушли к примеру в 3-4 очередь.

Comment: Ниче не понятно, но очень интересно

Comment: @eri так и думал)

Comment: я тоже наверное ничего не понял, вы хотите сделать что-то вроде лоад балансера?